# How to do a real transition with iOS instead of modal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

From what I understand, modal is sort of like a pop up presentation of a view controller? So that means that the view controller that is calling presentViewController is still there?

What is the proper way of transitioning to another view controller without it just being a modal popup? (Meaning it is not a parent-child relationship between the two, I guess)

Comment: What type of transitioning you need between 2 view controllers.

Comment: Refer this link.<https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW1>

Comment: So Modal and NavigationController's push are the only two types of transitions?

Comment: Can you explain to me the difference between showViewController and presentViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use NavigationController to push other ViewController. Sorry if i have wrong answer

This is guide about NavigationController for you 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1